# Python Script Won't Write to text file when run from OS X terminal

Tags: python, macos

So I've written a pretty basic script as part of a larger test of my system. Essentially, it just creates a new file *text.txt* and writes "abject failure" to the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "running"  
text_file = open("text.txt", "a")
text_file.write("abject failure")    
text_file.close()

print "success"
```

The script works wonderfully when I run from IDLE, but when I run from the Mac OS X terminal with

```
python /Users/.../serverside.py
```

I only get the "print" values but nothing is written to the *text.txt* file. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Copied the code, ran it per `python filename.py` and the text.txt file contained the expected text. When you call the script with an absolute path, that means you may be anywhere in the file system. The file is given with a relative path (only its name) thus it will be written in the present working directory where you "cd"ed into wbefore calling. Eg. `cd; python /somewhere/far/apart/script.py` will write the text.txt file into your home folder `${HOME}` because that is where you go when you type `cd` and enter

Comment: Works for me, are you checking the directory from which you have run the code?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that your script always works, no matter where your call is coming from, also set an absolute path to your file

```
text_file = open("/Users/path/to/file/text.txt", "a")
```

The other solution, as stated in the comment, is to change your working directory to the path where you want the file to be

```
cd /Users/path/to/file
python /Users/.../serverside.py
```